# jest coverageThreshold glob exclude some sub folders

Tags: jestjs, glob

Inside my `./src/app/global-team` folder, there are a-z folders.  I want to set my threshold level on all folders aggregated except d, f, and y. I want to get the aggregate numbers instead of numbers per folder/file.  My closest attempt is the following which reports the numbers by file:

```
coverageThreshold: {
  './src/app/global-team/!(d|f|y)/**': {
    branches: 95,
    functions: 95,
    lines: 95,
    statements: 95
  }
}
```

And removing the ** wild cards doesn't work: `'./src/app/global-team/!(d|f|y)/`

What would be the correct glob to exclude some subfolders but have the report at aggregate level?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [Jest Documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#coveragethreshold-object), you can specify multiple thresholds, and can use wild cards. While this is not the glob specific method, like collectCoverageFrom, it will support what you are trying to accomplish.

```
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 50,
        "functions": 50,
        "lines": 50,
        "statements": 50
      },
      "./src/components/": {
        "branches": 40,
        "statements": 40
      },
      "./src/reducers/**/*.js": {
        "statements": 90
      },
      "./src/api/very-important-module.js": {
        "branches": 100,
        "functions": 100,
        "lines": 100,
        "statements": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have my coverage set to cover the project, and in using the parent directory with a glob, then removing what I do not want to cover, I do get a source tree view.  This view then has folder 'A' with [image: overall coverage metrics] overall metrics.

Click into it, then the individual files (or more folders) with [image: their metrics] the metrics for that folder or file.

Likely still not want you want.  I have also run before the Jest

The next option is to create multiple jest.config.js files (jest.config.main.js, jest.config.projectb.js) and run Jest with each of these configuration files, but putting the output into different directories. I use this for test coverage during my e2e tests.

Again, not sure this fully does what you want.

Comment: This is not what I was asking.  I want to group the coverage numbers for all the non-excluded folders.